# jQuery select all but one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have html like below and want to select everything except for the `<a>` element. The end goal is to have two clickable areas and each do different things. But I have had trouble isolating the larger area from the `<a>` element.

```
<td title="title1" class="class1"> <p class="pclass1">value1</p></td>
<td>
    <p class="someClass1" title="someTitle1">someValue1</p>
    <p class="someClass2" title="someTitle2">someValue2</p></td>
    <p class="someClass3" title="someTitle3">someValue3</p>
</td>

<td><p title="otherTitle1" class="otherClass1">otherValue1</p></td>
<td><p title="otherTitle2" class="otherClass2">otherValue2</p></td>
<td><p title="otherTitle3" class="otherClass3">otherValue3</p></td>
<td><p title="otherTitle4" class="otherClass4">otherValue4</p></td>
<td title="title2" class="class2"><a href="#" class="no-select">don't select me</a></td>
```

So is it possible to select all of the 'td's except for that 'a' in the last 'td'?

I've tried things like `'td:not(a)', 'td:not(.no-select)'` with no success

Comment: Do you want a different action to happen when the user clicks the `<a>` than if they click on any other element?  Or would you just like nothing to happen if they click the `<a class="no-select">` ?

Comment: For the purpose of this question. I would like nothing to happen. I would use another selector to grab the <a> for another action.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to delegate the click handler to the common parent `tr` element and then detect which element raised the event and run the appropriate logic. Something like this:

```js
$('tr').click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is('.no-select')) {
    console.log('link clicked...');
  } else {
    console.log('row clicked...');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td title="title1" class="class1"><p class="pclass1">value1</p></td>
    <td>
      <p class="someClass1" title="someTitle1">someValue1</p>
      <p class="someClass2" title="someTitle2">someValue2</p>
    </td>
    <td><p class="someClass3" title="someTitle3">someValue3</p></td>
    <td><p title="otherTitle1" class="otherClass1">otherValue1</p></td>
    <td><p title="otherTitle2" class="otherClass2">otherValue2</p></td>
    <td><p title="otherTitle3" class="otherClass3">otherValue3</p></td>
    <td><p title="otherTitle4" class="otherClass4">otherValue4</p></td>
    <td title="title2" class="class2"><a href="#" class="no-select">don't select me</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to check the classname of the `target` element on the event.

```
$("td").on("click", function(e) {

  if (e.target.className === 'no-select') {
    return;
  }

  // Now we can do something here because we know
  // the event wasn't triggered by a `no-select` element
});
```